# Shiny where do you create dataset based on reactive input to use later in the app

Tags: r, shiny

I have a relatively heavy programme to run based on manually selected input. I would like to have my app such that users select parameters, pres go and then a database is created that can be used to create multiple tables and graphs based on this dataset. But creating the database can only happen once.

Up to now the database is created before running the app, based on user input. See code below for an example.

```
countries <- c("BEL", "FRA", "AFG")
el_inf_ex <- 1


df_TEST <-data.frame(iso3= c(rep("BEL", 10),rep("FRA", 10),rep("AFG", 10)), 
                     year= c(seq(2001, 2010), seq(2001, 2010), seq(2001, 2010)),
                     test= rnorm(30)*el_inf_ex)



#The shiney appp has three parts

  ui <- fluidPage(
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("TEST"),

    # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(

# 1 Where you select user input ----
      sidebarPanel(

        # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----
        selectInput(inputId = "Country",
                    label = "Choose a country:",
                    choices = countries),

        # Input: Numeric entry for number of obs to view ----
        sliderInput(inputId = "Year",
                    label = "Choose a year:",
                    value = 2018,
                    min = 2000,
                    max = 2010),
        # Input: Numeric entry for number of obs to view ----
        sliderInput(inputId = "el_inf_ex",
                    label = "El(inf,exrate):",
                    value = 0.3,
                    min = 0,
                    max = 1)
      ),
# 2 Where you specify the output ----
        mainPanel(

          # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
          tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                      tabPanel("Data Input No shock", 
                               # Output: HTML table with requested number of observations ----
                               h3("I. One title:"),
                               tableOutput("CI"),
                               h3("II. Second title:"),
                               tableOutput("VUL")
                      )
          )
        )
      )
)


    # Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
    server <- function(input, output) {

      # Return the MonArr variable
      datasetInput_CI <- reactive({
        df_TEST %>% filter(iso3 == input$Country, year == input$Year) %>% summarise(blabla = max(test))
      })
      # Return the Vulnerability variables ----
      datasetInput_Vul <- reactive({
        df_TEST %>% filter(iso3 == input$Country, year == input$Year) 
      })
      output$CI <- renderTable(datasetInput_CI())
      output$VUL <- renderTable(datasetInput_Vul())
    }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would thus like to create the dataframe df_TEST in the code such that el_inf_ex can be selected in the app, but the the lines to create the dataset can only be run once. (In my actual application I will have to source other R files) Afterwards, I want to use the output (the dataframe df_TEST) in graphs and tables.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. The trick is to use the function observe(). Within this function the dataset can be created.

I changed some parts of the example to make everything respond to the button "Update".

```
countries <- c("BEL", "FRA", "AFG")

#The shiney appp has three parts

  ui <- fluidPage(
    # App title ----
    titlePanel("TEST"),

    # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions ----
    sidebarLayout(

# 1 Where you select user input ----
      sidebarPanel(

        # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----
        selectInput(inputId = "Country",
                    label = "Choose a country:",
                    choices = countries),

        # Input: Numeric entry for number of obs to view ----
        sliderInput(inputId = "Year",
                    label = "Choose a year:",
                    value = 2018,
                    min = 2000,
                    max = 2010),
        # Input: Numeric entry for number of obs to view ----
        sliderInput(inputId = "el_inf_ex",
                    label = "El(inf,exrate):",
                    value = 0.3,
                    min = 0,
                    max = 10),      
        actionButton("update", "Update")
      ),
# 2 Where you specify the output ----
        mainPanel(

          # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
          tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                      tabPanel("Data Input No shock", 
                               # Output: HTML table with requested number of observations ----
                               h3("I. One title:"),
                               tableOutput("CI"),
                               h3("II. Second title:"),
                               tableOutput("VUL")
                      )
          )
        )
      )
)


    # Define server logic to summarize and view selected dataset ----
    server <- function(input, output) {
      Output <-  reactiveValues(datasetInput_CI = NULL)
      Output <-  reactiveValues(datasetInput_Vul = NULL)


      storage <- reactiveValues()
      observe({
        storage$df_Test <- data.frame(iso3= c(rep("BEL", 10),rep("FRA", 10),rep("AFG", 10)), 
                            year= c(seq(2001, 2010), seq(2001, 2010), seq(2001, 2010)),
                            test= rnorm(30)*input$el_inf_ex)
      })

      # Return the MonArr variable
      observeEvent(input$update, {
        Output$datasetInput_CI <- storage$df_Test %>% filter(iso3 == input$Country, year == input$Year) %>% summarise(blabla = max(test))
      })
      # Return the Vulnerability variables ----
      observeEvent(input$update, {

        Output$datasetInput_Vul <- storage$df_Test %>% filter(iso3 == input$Country, year == input$Year) 
      })
      output$CI <- renderTable(Output$datasetInput_CI)
      output$VUL <- renderTable(Output$datasetInput_Vul)
    }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```